# Best way to operate a UIImagePickerController from a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom UITableViewCell declared thusly:

```
@interface ValveCell : UITableViewCell <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

A button which hooks to the following method:

```
- (void) addPicture {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    // I have tried every possible value for the presentation style
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationNone;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // controller is a @property I added to my custom class
    // it is the UIViewController that is the data source/delegate for the table view
    [self.controller presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

And the supporting delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (chosenImage) {
        [self.valve pushPhoto: chosenImage];}
}
```

There are two issues (at least) I'm having with this code:

1. Every time I click the button, I get the following warning in my transcript: *"Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."*  I've tried the various presentation styles. I don't know why this is happening, or what I need to do to make it go away.
2. It bothers me that I have to hand a controller to the cell (in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method). I know walking the `superView` chain is frowned upon. Is there a no better way to get a controller to open it from? Or an alternate way of opening the picker that doesn't need a controller? Even something like `self.tableView.delegate` would work if cells but had a back pointer to their tableview.

**UPDATE**

Answer for #1 goes to @Jiten Parmar below. As for #2, I found the PPTopMostController pod which allowed me to use the code:

```
[UIViewController topMostController]
```

which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."`

The answer is that when your app is in the portrait mode and you open the image picker with landscape it will show this warning in the console, but no need to worry that, it is not critical for your app and no crash issue will be there.

Comment: I confirmed that if I turn off the other orientation modes in the main project page, this "warning" no longer shows up.